# When searching on Google, how do I show more on the autocomplete list (drop down list)?

Tags: google-search

Currently it only show 4 possible autocompletes when I'm typing something in the search box, does anyone know how to increase that?

This is for Windows 10.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way currently to change the number of [autocomplete](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106230?hl=en) entries seen.